# Target all descendants of an element

Tags: css

Say I have the following html:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="form">
            <h1>headline</h1>
            <input name="input-name"/>
            <p>
                <h2>subheadline</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    some content
                </div>             
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And I want every element inside body to be `inline` (I know it doesn't make any sense, just for the example), so is there some elegant way to do that, rather then:

```
.wrapper,
form,
h1,
input[name='input-name'],
h2,
.content{
    display: inline;
}
```

?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to set all to inline but you can use `body *` or `body > *` as you wish.

Comment: Just for the example..

Comment: Side note, h2 and div are not allowed to be inside p tag.